# Create system group from hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

is it possible to create a system group from hiera?
I know how to create a system group in the manifest via [class](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.4/types/group.html#group-attribute-gid), but I have failed to move that to hiera

Any example of creating a systemgroup "foo" with gid "1000" in hiera would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiera is a *data* service.  It can provide data about system groups, or about any kind of resource at all, but you need at least a little bit of manifest code somewhere to make a resource declaration out of that.  For example, this pushes all the details out of the manifest and into Hiera (or other manifest code):

```
class mymodule::groups(Hash[String, Hash] $groupdata) {
    $groupdata.each |$gname, $params| {
        group { $gname: * => $params }
    }
}
```

Hiera data feeding that class might look something like this:

```
mymodule::groups::groupdata:
  group1:
    system: true
  group2:
    gid:    42
    system: true
  group3:
    ensure: absent
```

The value for `$groupdata` is, as declared by the class, a Hash of Hashes.  The keys are group names, and the values are hashes of property names and values for the built-in `Group` resource type.

There are many other ways that one could accomplish this, with different advantages and disadvantages.  I present this one because it is among the simplest.